# How is it possible to provide a shining color?

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, colortbl

I want to provide a beautiful color for my picture. Also, for example the below picture has a shining and beautiful picture.

[image]

```
  \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{-60}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{\x}{\y}
\newcommand*{\gridstep}{0.15}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\filldraw[fill=white,looseness=1] (3.6,0,-21) coordinate (under surface right) to[bend right] (1.7,3.2,-13) coordinate (under surface left) -- coordinate (middle left) (1.8,3.5,-12) coordinate (bottom left) to[bend left] (4,0,-22) coordinate (bottom right) -- coordinate (middle right) cycle;
\filldraw[fill=green!20,looseness=1] (4,0,-22) to[bend right] (1.8,3.5,-12) -- (1.8,3.5,30) coordinate (top left) to[bend left] (4,0,20) coordinate (top right) -- cycle;

\foreach[count=\ii] \i in {0,\gridstep,...,1}{
        \path (bottom left) to[bend left] coordinate[pos=\i](p\ii) (bottom right);
        \path (under surface left) to[bend left] coordinate[pos=\i](k\ii) (under surface right);
        \draw (p\ii) -- ++(0,0,42);
        \draw (p\ii) -- (k\ii);
        \draw ($(bottom left)!\i!(top left)$) to[bend left] ($(bottom right)!\i!(top right)$);
        };
\draw (middle left) to[bend left] (middle right);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can't do this with PGF/Ti*k*Z. Well, you could since you could theoretically draw pixel by pixel or something. But you don't want to. You need software that handles 3D and, in particular, can work with surfaces of specified reflectance and light sources of specified kinds etc. PGF/Ti*k*Z can't do this. Period. You can make something pretty, but if that image represents your aim, then you are going to be disappointed by anything PGF/Ti*k*Z can do. Pick an appropriate tool for the job or modify your expectations.

Comment: Thank you... so, what is the final picture with a beautiful color in Tikz? can you show me an example? Or modify the presented example?

Comment: That original is slightly distorted from http://www.edmundoptics.co.uk/optics/optical-lenses/plano-convex-pcx-spherical-singlet-lenses/silicon-plano-convex-pcx-lenses/69673/ Edmund normally use (rather dramatically lit) photographs to illustrate their products.  Alternatively this could be ray-traced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using `\shade` instead of `\filldraw`?

[image: With ball effect]

Ti*k*Z has a `shadings` library to make rflection *like* effects. It's not perfect as @cfr mentioned in the comments: there's a tool for everything.

Several other effects can be obtained with the library, the above image used `ball color = white`, while the below used the `axis` scheme setting `left color=gray, right color=white`. As @cfr also said, reflection effects are light dependent which means to draw them correctly one has to deal with light sources, not done by Ti*k*Z, the best we can do is try to simulate these effects with shadings...

For even more possible effects check [the manual](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) under Libraries > Shadings

[image: with axis effect]

The complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shadings}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{-60}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{\x}{\y}
\newcommand*{\gridstep}{0.15}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\filldraw[fill=white,looseness=1] (3.6,0,-21) coordinate (under surface right) to[bend right] (1.7,3.2,-13) coordinate (under surface left) -- coordinate (middle left) (1.8,3.5,-12) coordinate (bottom left) to[bend left] (4,0,-22) coordinate (bottom right) -- coordinate (middle right) cycle;
\shade[left color=gray, right color=white, draw]% << change shading effects here
(4,0,-22) to[bend right] (1.8,3.5,-12) -- (1.8,3.5,30) coordinate (top left) to[bend left] (4,0,20) coordinate (top right) -- cycle;

\foreach[count=\ii] \i in {0,\gridstep,...,1}{
        \path (bottom left) to[bend left] coordinate[pos=\i](p\ii) (bottom right);
        \path (under surface left) to[bend left] coordinate[pos=\i](k\ii) (under surface right);
        \draw (p\ii) -- ++(0,0,42);
        \draw (p\ii) -- (k\ii);
        \draw ($(bottom left)!\i!(top left)$) to[bend left] ($(bottom right)!\i!(top right)$);
        };
\draw (middle left) to[bend left] (middle right);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```